# PHP -- Looping through mysqli_fetch_array results adds extra products to rows

Tags: php, html

I'm having a problem with some code I've written to display products by category and allow customers to choose the size they want. I'm sure it's a simple solution, and almost as certain the problem stems from my lack of understanding how the msqli_fetch_assoc while loop actually works.

The problem is that the first row shows the first product correctly, but the second not just the secone product, but the first and second products. The third row shows the first three products, and so on.

Here is my complete code (please ignore the JQuery/Javascript, I'm brand new to it and will likely be back for help with that in another post.) I've been staring at it for hours. Can someone point out where I've gone wrong here?

```
<?php 
session_start();

$dbserver = 'localhost';
    $dbname = '########';
    $dbuser = '########';
    $dbpassword = '########';

    $category = $_GET['category'];
    $db = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_select_db($db, $dbname);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '".$category."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if (!$result) {
        die ('Error: Could not select products'.mysqli_error($db));
    } 

   function make_size_select($product) {
    echo '<select name="unit_menu">';
    $price_set = array(
        'halfpint'=>$product['halfpint'],
        'pint'=>$product['pint'],
        'dk'=>$product['dk'],
        'quart'=>$product['quart']);

    $handles = array(
        'halfpint'=>'Half Pint (8 oz)',
        'pint'=>'Pint (16 oz)',
        'dk'=>'Dutch Kettle (16 oz)',
        'quart'=>'Quart (32 oz)');

    foreach ($price_set as $key=>$value) {
        if ( $value > 0.00) {
            echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$handles[$key].'</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Smoky Mountain Honey House</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
  <link href="../css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/menu.js"></script> 
  <script>
  $(window).load(function() {
    var product = $.getJSON(<?php echo json_encode($result); ?>);
    showUnitPrice(product);
    showRowTotal(product);
  });

   // show the price for a single unit based on current values for unit_size and unit_type
  function setUnitPrice(product) {
    // get the value for unit_type
    var item_type = $.closest('.unit_type');
    // get the value for unit size
    var item_size = $.closest('.unit_size');

    // Get the base price for the item
    var unit_price = Object.keys(product[item_size]);

    // If the unit type is 'ind', divide the price by 12
    if (item_type.value == "ind") {
        unit_price = unit_price / 12;
    }

    return unit_price;
 }

 function showUnitPrice(product) {
    var unit_price = setUnitPrice(product);
    $(this).closest('.unit_price').val(unit_price);
 }

 function showRowTotal(product) {
    var unit_price = setUnitPrice(product);
    var row_price = unit_price * $(this).closest('.qty').value;
    $(this).closest('row_price').val(row_price);
 }



    </script>
 </head>
<body>
    <!----start-header----->

<div class="header_img">
     <div class="himage_half"><img src="../images/honeyhouse-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="himage_half">
        <script>
        $(document).load() {
            $(this).load('template/js/cart/cart.html');
        }
</script>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="header">                
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="../index.php"><img src="../images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <nav class="clearfix">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="../index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="../about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="../locations.html">LOCATIONS</a></li>
                <li><a href="../shop.html">SHOP</a></li>
                <li><a href="../contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

   <!----End-header----->

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
    <?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $products[] = $row;
    foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <div class="product_row">
        <form name="order_row_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" action="#" method="post">
            <div class="product_cell product_id">
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
                <?php echo ucfirst($product['name']); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="product_cell">
                <select name="unit_type" onChange="showUnitPrice(product);">
                    <option value="ind" selected>By the Jar</option>
                    <option value="case">By the Case</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="product_cell unit_menu"">
                <?php echo make_size_select($product); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="product_cell qty">
                <input type="number" name="qty" max="11" label="How many?" />
            </div>
            <div class="product_cell unit-price"></div>
            <div class="product_cell row-price"></div>
            <div class="product_cell">
                <button class="add-to-cart" onclick="addToCart();">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    <?php }}; ?>

  </div> 
  </div>


<div class="copy-right">
        <p>&copy; 2016 Smoky Mountain Honey House</p>
        <p>Template by <a href="http://w3layouts.com/"> W3layouts</a></p>
</div>
 <!---End-footer---->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wait a minute.. at first i thought nothing wrong with this, but then.. `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` this retrieve and printing all products that belong to all category right? but then, what `foreach ($products as $product) {` do..? your query are fetching products that belong to a category right..? -- `$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '".$category."'";`

Comment: `var product = $.getJSON(<?php echo json_encode($result); ?>);` makes no sense. `$.getJSON` is for fetching remote data, but by doing `echo json_encode($result);` you're making your json object into the URL that `$.getJSON` will try and call to fetch the data! See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ . This is probably causing an error. `var product = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;` should be quite sufficient to embed the data directly into the JS as an object.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Bagus' suggestions helped me fix the issue, and ADyson helped deal with another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the suggestion of Bagus Tesa, I took out the for each loop, edited the rest to account for that, and the problem is solved. Thanks, Bagus!

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$counter = array();

while ( $row =  mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {

    foreach ( $row as $product ) { 

        $counter[ $product[ 'id' ] ] = $product[ 'id' ]; 
        /* run a condition statement here before outputting the result if need arises */

        /* this will prevent duplicate product listing */
        if ( $counter[ $product[ 'id' ] ]  == $product[ 'id' ] ) {
            // display product
        }

    }
}
```